# Item is not remove from observable collection

Tags: xamarin, observablecollection, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin.forms app,I found a problem, in my cart page I have a + button while clicking on the button item add to cart if I click again it will remove, but I can't remove an item after navigate back to from cart page.

```
btn_Cart.Clicked += (sender, e) =>{
                    sender = BindingContext;
                    cm_items item = (cm_items)sender;
                    Int32 inItemId = (BindingContext as cm_items).item_id;
                    var count = App.Instance.ViewModel.TempList.Count;
                    var value = App.Instance.ViewModel.TempList;
                    Boolean blInsertStatus = true;
                    try{
                        if (count == 0) {
                            item.IsAddedToCart = true;
                            value.Add(item);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                            {
                                if (value [i].item_id == inItemId)
                                {                                                                        
                                    value.Remove(item);
                                    blInsertStatus = false;
                                    item.IsAddedToCart = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (blInsertStatus)
                            {
                                if (item.IsAddedToCart)
                                {
                                    item.IsAddedToCart = false;
                                    value.Remove(item);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    item.IsAddedToCart = true;
                                    value.Add(item);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }                        
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                        throw;
                    } };
```

When I removing an item on first time there is no problem but after  navigate to different page it creates trouble.item is not getting removed and image does not get changed.what is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your event gets registered twice and that this causes trouble?

First visit on the page: btn_Cart.Clicked += ...

Second visit on the page: btn_Cart.Clicked += ...

How often gets "btn_Cart.Clicked" called? For furhter debugging, I suggest to add some debug output. Something like: "Item added", "Item removed". That way you can see what your code actually does.

Comment: i'm using xamairn.forms  and i can fire the click event on each click . i'm not understanding that what you posted ?

Comment: If you add a debug output after every value.Remove(item); and value.Add(item); - do you get the expected output? I was talking about event registration. Perhaps it gets registered more than once. That way your function would be executed two or more times after you click on the button.

Comment: i can add and remove on first but when i came back from the page i cant remove the added item . this is what my problem

Comment: Yes, yes, I think I understood your problem. Can you output some debug information or step through the code?

Comment: i can explain , on the first time the count is "0" so value can directly save if a item a saved i will put  IsAddedToCart = true  for change the image . initially the button image is + after adding the item it will change to -  .but if the collection contain a value  we have to check for duplication here i check using item_id and if contain item will removed this is what i'm doing but not working . it works on first time but not working after came back to other page . i cant post my debug , i don't know how to post it

Comment: Please add a debug output above "sender = BindingContext;" and see how often it gets written and tell me. If it is only once, we can skip the scenario mentioned above with the double registratin! ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96687/discussion-between-timtos-and-shamnad).